# Error 1005 laravel because of migrations priorities

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have some tables that are connected to each other.
I should declare foreign key for those.
When I do this by migrations, the error 1005 appear.
I know that this error is due to migrations priorities.
Now I don't know how to solve this problem.

This is one of my migrations:
[image: categories migration]

and this is another one:
[image: colors migration]

And finally, the most important migration is:
[image: products migration]

and I don't know how to declare foreign keys in another migration.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: dont post images of text, code is text

Comment: `products.category_en` is a string, but it references `categories.id`, an unsigned integer. Same with the `_fa` variant, the color-related columns, and what I suspect to be the other id columns.

Comment: Error 1005 is related to foreign key errors. Check if the related tables/fields exist before (creating the depending tables first) andcheck if the fields use the same types in both sides.

Comment: @lagbox I’m really awfully sorry, im beginner.

Comment: no worries, you didn't know, im just informing you that this makes everything more difficult and also makes it very difficult for anyone with accessibility issues to help ... for future reference

Comment: @ChrisForrence Thank you kindly, the problem was solved. the column type was wrong.

Comment: @F.Igor Thank you very much. I checked the types of fields and find the problem.

Comment: @lagbox Yes, i know, as i said before, i'm a beginner. Thank you very much.

Comment: no worries, good luck with your project and enjoy using Laravel :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two primary issues:

- The product table's foreign keys have different datatypes than the related table's data type. That is, products.category_en is defined as a string, but categories.id is defined as an unsigned integer.
- The `category_product` and `color_product` tables are defined before the `products` table has been defined; these tables should be defined after the categories/colors/products/etc. tables have been defined- I'd recommend defining each in a separate migration file.

Comment: Thank you kindly. This is the solution I found a few minutes ago.